# How can I make the Devise PasswordController skip a User validation?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I have a Rails app where I am using Devise for authentication. Devise lets users click to get an email containing a link to reset their password.

When the user gives the new password, `Devise::PasswordsController#edit` is invoked, but the password is actually updated on the `User` model, which is then saved.

My problem is that `User` has a validation which may fail during the password reset, preventing it from saving the changes to the User model. **I want to ignore that validation when resetting the password.**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a conditional validation on your user model that will not run that validation if the password confirmation is blank (they are not changing their password).  To accomplish this you would use the following:

```
validates :accepted_terms_at, 
  :presence => {:if => proc {|u| u.password_confirmation.blank?}}
```

Update for your validation needs.  Validation in `ActiveModel` lets you provide a proc to run :if and :unless to conditionally validate.  That proc will get passed the current instance (a user instance in your case) to determine if the validation should run.

Thanks!